# How do I create a workflow rule to populate price book based on account?

Tags: workflow, pricebook

I am trying to create a workflow rule (let me know if there is a better approach) so that when an opportunity is created and the account field is completed, the price book field in the opportunity will be automatically populated with the price book for the account.  So far I have setup a rule so that the workflow rule runs when opportunity:active=True, however when setting up the field update I do not see an option to update the price book field.  Please help.  I've been stuck working on this for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While standard workflow rules will not allow you to update the Pricebook2ID the process builder will allow you to do it:

[image]

Otherwise your only other option would be to write a trigger